# Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: php

subí mi página a `000webhost` y al momento de iniciar sesión sale todo bien excepto que me aparece este error

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   /storage/ssd5/679/2763679/public_html/LF/html/ico_notif.php:1) in
>   /storage/ssd5/679/2763679/public_html/LF/html/ico_notif.php on line 2

En ese `PHP` tengo esto

(lógicamente aunque no este allí tengo abierto y cerrado el `php`)

```
session_start();
require('funciones.php');
require('clases.php');
$usuario = usuarios::usuario_por_codigo($_SESSION["CodUsua"]);
```

Comment: ¿Has investigado la [posible causa de este error](https://www.google.com.co/search?q=session_start()%3A+Cannot+send+session+cache+limiter+-+headers+already+sent&rlz=1C1GGRV_esCO751CO751&oq=session_start()%3A+Cannot+send+session+cache+limiter+-+headers+already+sent&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba poniendo esto al principio del documento :

```
@ob_start();
session_start();
require('funciones.php');
require('clases.php');
$usuario = usuarios::usuario_por_codigo($_SESSION["CodUsua"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Headers already sent` significa que en código, PHP ya ha enviado los encabezados HTTP, y por lo tanto no puede hacer modificaciones de nuevo hasta que la sesión se limpie del encabezado.

Verifica que no llamas antes a `session_start`. Mejor aún, sólo ten un `session_start` en tu archivo PHP (así que ponlo en el comienzo absoluto, antes de todo HTML, etc).

Ref: Traducción al Español de la respuesta de [@houbysoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363078/houbysoft) en [SO en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812754/cannot-send-session-cache-limiter-headers-already-sent#8812777).